# Angular CLI and StyleUrls

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-components

I'm still new to Angular and noticed if providing StyleUrls property to components they seem to not be integrated in styles.js automatically, but only if I import it inside my main styles-file.
Actually I thought, this is not necessary and now I'm asking myself for what I am adding the StyleUrls for?! Did I miss something in configuration or settings? Is it because I'm using LESS?

Any advice is really appreciated.

Cheers,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I'm just answering myself and for all the other beginners facing the same issue in now and in future:

My problem was in misunderstanding the styles behaviour in Angular.

Let's say we have a component `app.component.ts` with a selector `app-root` and a style file `app.component.css` (or less or whatever) which is added to component's property `styleUrls`.
Now if I add my styling for selector `app-root` to component's style sheet it **won't** be recognized. If I add it to global `styles.css` (or less or whatever) it **will** be recognized.

### Conclusion

Angular **only** recognizes style selectors in style files **for child elements** of the component, but not for the component's root element itself (which I still find confusing).

Comment: You can use the :host pseudo class to target the component root element. Find out more here https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/

Answer (score 0):

you can ddd your global less files to styles section in angular-cli.json file:

```
"styles": [ "my-style.less", 
             "styles.css"]
```

and in your component you can use:

```
styleUrls: ['./component.less']
```

you can create a new app like this in case of using less:

```
ng new your_project --style less
```

Comment: And exactly component is not working. I've tried all possible paths for styleUrls, but the content of them is ignored/not added. If path isn't correct, Webpack is complaining correctly, so the paths at least seem to be recognized. But Angular isn't loading them. Only if I add them as "import" statement to global styles.less.